# R Statistics Distributions Plotting

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I am having some trouble with a homework I have at Statistics.

I am required to graphical represent the density and the distribution function in two inline plots for a set of parameters at my choice ( there must be minimum 4 ) for Student, Fisher and ChiS repartitions.

Let's take only the example of Student Repartition.

From what I have searched on the internet, I have come with this:

First, I need to generate some random values.

```
x <- rnorm( 20, 0, 1 )
```

Question 1: I need to generate 4 of this?

Then I have to plot these values with:

```
plot(dt( x, df = 1))
plot(pt( x, df = 1))
```

But, how to do this for four set of parameters? They should be represented in the same plot.

Is this the good approach to what I came so far?
Please, tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: see `?lines`, `?points` ...

Comment: See also `?matplot`. To generate 4 times that use `replicate(4, rnorm(20))`.

Comment: ok thanks for your answers. @RuiBarradas is ok what i do ? generating those random values and then using dt and pt ? Is that what i am required to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot several densities of a certain distribution, you have to first have a support vector, in this case `x` below.
Then compute the values of the densities with the parameters of your choice.
Then plot them.

In the code that follows, I will plot 4 Sudent-t pdf's, with degrees of freedom 1 to 4.

```
x <- seq(-5, 5, by = 0.01)    # The support vector
y <- sapply(1:4, function(d) dt(x, df = d))

# Open an empty plot first
plot(1, type = "n", xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(0, 0.5))
for(i in 1:4){
    lines(x, y[, i], col = i)
}
```

Then you can make the graph prettier, by adding a main title, changing the axis titles, etc.

If you want other distributions, such as the F or Chi-squared, you will use `x` strictly positive, for instance `x <- seq(0.0001, 10, by = 0.01)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! For my better understanding: set of parameters at my choice ( there must be minimum 4 )  in your solution is represented by the degrees or freedom? or i should have 4 x vectors ? and also, for F and Chi-squared, i can use the same code ?

Comment: if i change dt( .. to df( ... i got: Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ. what i have to do ?

Comment: 1) Yes, the set of parameters are the degrees or freedom. 2) For the F distribution you must use `x` as in the last sentence of my answer, then maybe something like `df(x, df1 = d, df2 = 3)`. (Or any other choice of degrees of freedom.) Then you will need to play with the value of `ylim`. I have tried `ylim = c(0, 1)`.